# Is there currently any way to provide RSA key based authentication in a browser?

Tags: security, authentication, browser, rsa

It seems like an attractive idea as far as both security and convenience would be to allow browsers to use RSA keys like you can do with ssh connections. I can imagine that a browser could interface with something like Pageant (if you're talking windows) to provide your public key as well as sign whatever's needed with your private key. Is this possible with current browsers?

Comment: Browsers support TLS client authentication, though it is rarely used.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Hmm, yeah, I mean the usability is terrible for that. Has there been any improvement, or is it still terrible?

Comment: A lot of related work in this context is being done by the FIDO alliance (fidoalliance.org). Their second factor authentication spec (U2F) is currently available in Chrome and a Firefox implementation is underway. The second version of their spec (FIDO 2.0) is on the W3C standards track: https://www.w3.org/Submission/2015/SUBM-fido-web-api-20151120/

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Interesting, its hard to get a feel for how it would operate in practice from the spec tho.

Comment: Why the downvote and close vote?

Comment: The basic idea is that you have an authenticator (first or second factor) that relies on a secure element (or trusted execution environment/trusted platform module) to generate/store the key material and perform the crypto operations. The actual user authentication is done in most cases through some form of biometrics (fingerprint/iris scan, facial recognition, ...), but for second factor authentication it can be as simple as just touching the authenticator to indicate user presence. There's already a bunch of FIDO U2F/UAF authenticators out there (YubiKey, Samsung Galaxy phones, etc.)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Very cool. Looks like MDN is working on docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:maybe/webidl_mdn/FIDO_API

Comment: Yeah, I would expect so. Back in January, I talked to the Mozilla engineer who is leading this effort and they're not disclosing an official timeline, but he expected the U2F implementation to be ready for desktop versions of Firefox some time this year.

Comment: For anyone interested, I just created this: https://github.com/webkey-auth/webkey-auth.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [TLS Client Certificates do](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/09/15/securing-access-using-tlsssl-client-certificates/).

RSA public and private key pairs can be used.

Although practically it is of [little value](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23893/8340) and has [problems of its own](http://www.browserauth.net/tls-client-authentication).

Comment: Thanks for the good links! I completely forgot about client-certs, for pretty much all those reasons.